# CRUD operation RDF library

Tags: sparql, rdf, easyrdf

I'm just starting to learn about the semantic web. can I perform CRUD operations using EasyRDF or other libraries?

previously I saw other libraries like Sparqllib in PHP. there is very simple and has no commands to create, update, delete

Comment: the question would be, what exactly you consider as a create or an edit in RDF data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems you can. [Read here](https://www.easyrdf.org/docs/api/EasyRdf/Sparql/Client.html). There are some abtracted methods for clearing named graphs, and updating specified triples too.

Assuming you have the DB permissions, and the ability to execute SPARQL, you should be able to perform CRUD operations.

Does it have to be EasyRDF? If you were considering python [SPARQLWrapper](https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html) is lightweight and very intuitive as a starting point.